# Display products by category in Woocommerce cart page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to display products grouped by tags or category in a Woocommerce cart page. For example a list of RED WINES and a list of WHITE WINES in order page or cart page.

In cart page:

Red Wines:

- Red Wine 1          10€
- Red Wine 2          10€

White Wines:

- White Wines 1       10€
- White Wines 1       10€

Total Cart:            40€

Thanks!!!!